# Android Studio| MediaPlayer| My function can run one time, then the app will crash | MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)

Tags: java, android

```
//this is inside onCreate function
//layoutRost is declared as private, inside onCreate is initialized, also speak_rost...
layoutRost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                speak_rost.start();

                speak_rost.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        speak_rost.release();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

First time I press it, the button & audio works well, second time I get the error: Open app again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//just initialize inside ClickListener, speak_rost, and after .setOnCompletionListener, I put speak_rost().start; that was ALL, very nice problem, now all my 50+ buttons/layouts are "in the right form" to play 100+ time, every time I needed. Thank you.
layoutRost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                speak_rost = MediaPlayer.create(hundred.this, R.raw.asa);
                speak_rost .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mysound) {
                        mysound.release();
                    }

                });
                speak_rost .start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last touched Android, I created my own method for playing sounds and it worked fine considering I published an app, so maybe it would help

```
//method that plays a sound effects
public void playMedia(int resid){
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,resid);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Every time there was something to play I would pass the id of the resource to this method

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try right now. int resid must be int layoutRost for example, is my id? I'm a little confused...

Comment: resid should be the id of the resource you are trying to play for example, let's say you have a file called niceSound that is located in your res folder, in another folder named raw; path will look like this appname/res/raw/niceSound.wav, in order to play you will call playMedia like this:    playMedia(R.raw.niceSound);

Comment: My function: <code> public void playSound(I_don't_know_what_to_put_here){
        speak_rost = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asa);
        speak_rost.start();
        speak_rost.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }</code>

Comment: Ok, I understood that in speak_rost = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asa); but I don't know what to put inside 'public void playSound(...)', why int...

Comment: then just try doing that assignment within a method that you will every time you want to play that sound, maybe it help, and layoutRost is it the layout used for your activity?

Comment: (Sorry for my late response...) Yes, layoutRost as a layout, as you see above..., by the way, I have 50 layouts, for each one I want to play a different sound, I can do that for all 50, but if I play twice the same layout, the app crashes. After several implementations with different methods, I saw that I have the error MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19), but even here in stackoverflow.com, I can't  find the right method for my app, or I'm too confused.